# How do I prevent duplication of generated code for a generic class?

Tags: delphi, generics

Delphi has a nasty habit of duplicating code for generic classes. Even if that code is really the same, because the generic types are similar.
I want to prevent duplication for storing different classes.
In my generic container I only use `Free` to clean up if needed.

Suppose I have a generic container like so:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyContainer<T> = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FData: TList<T>;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;
```

I know `T` will often be an object. Because all objects are really `TObject` I don't want my container to create duplicate generic code for different types of objects.

Will the following trick work to prevent duplication?

A- Substitute the constructor with a class function:

```
unit Unit2;

uses Unit1;

type
  TMyContainer<T> = class(Unit1.TMyContainer<T>)
  public
    class function Create: TMyContainer<T>; static;
  end;
```

B: implement the class function `Create` like so:

```
class function TMyContainer<T>.Create: TMyContainer<T>;
var
  X: TObject;
begin
  if GetTypeKind(T) = tkClass then begin
    X:= Unit1.TMyContainer<TObject>.Create;
  end else begin
    X:= Unit1.TMyContainer<T>.Create;
  end;
  TObject(Result):= X;
end;
```

Will this trick work to prevent the compiler from generating duplicate code for different types of objects, or will this fail because I'm using incorrect assumptions?
Note that I don't want to resort to using a non-generic store for my data.

**Full sample code follows**

```
unit Unit49;

interface

uses Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyContainer<T> = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FData: TList<T>;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyContainer<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FData:= TList<T>.Create;
end;

end.
```

**Sample program**

```
program Project85;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit49 in 'Unit49.pas';

type
  TMyContainer<T> = class(Unit49.TMyContainer<T>)
  public
    class function Create: TMyContainer<T>; static;
  end;

{ TMyContainer<T> }

class function TMyContainer<T>.Create: TMyContainer<T>;
var
  Y: T;
  X: TObject;
begin
  if GetTypeKind(T) = tkClass then begin
    X:= Unit49.TMyContainer<TObject>.Create;
  end else begin
    X:= Unit49.TMyContainer<T>.Create;
  end;
  TObject(Result):= X;
end;

var
  A: TMyContainer<TObject>;
  B: TMyContainer<TLanguages>;

begin
  A:= TMyContainer<TObject>.Create;
  B:= TMyContainer<TLanguages>.Create;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Because I have legacy code that doesn't just port itself....

Comment: Anyway, I think the recognised tricks are exemplified in recent Generics.Collections. I'd read the XE8 diffs against XE7. Think Spring4d did similar.

Comment: OK, I'll  check it out.

Answer (score 4):

> Will this trick work to prevent the compiler from generating duplicate
>   code for different types of objects, or will this fail because I'm
>   using incorrect assumptions?

No, it will not work.

Basically, compiler follows your `T` through whole class hierarchy and replaces it with specific type.

For start, you will have separate `TList<T>` code generated for both `TObject` and `TLanguages` because your container is declared as `FData: TList<T>`, then 
your trick collection also inherits from generic `T` `TMyContainer<T> = class(Unit49.TMyContainer<T>)` and whole code in your class function is basically useless.

Compiler will generate duplicate code for `Unit49.TMyContainer<TLanguages>` class as well as `Unit49.TMyContainer<TObject>` class.

From your example it is hard to say what code duplication are you trying to avoid. If container class is as simple as you have written in your example, then all code duplication will come from `TList<T>` class. If you are trying to avoid that one, there is no easy way out.

Part of your problem comes from fact that you have `T` that can be anything. It is hard to optimize it. The most optimization you could get is using `array of T` for storing data and then delegating manipulation functions where you can use `TObject` as base for all classes and plain `T` for others.

How much can you gain with above also depends on which Delphi version do you use, because in most recent versions `TList<T>` has been optimized a bit with similar techniques.

However, if you can have separate containers for class and other types then you can achieve code folding for `TObject` and descendant containers using `TObjectList<TObject>` (or even non generic `TObjectList` on Windows) for storing all specific classes and implementing thin wrapper functions with typecast for any type safe functions you need. Of course, each such function will have some code generated for each specific type, but since they are just typecast wrappers that will not be as much code as it would be if you would use full `TList<T>` for each class type.

```
  TMyObjectContainer<T> = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FData: TObjectList<TObject>; 
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;  
    function Data(index: integer): T;
  end;

constructor TMyObjectContainer<T>.Create; 
begin
  inherited;
  FData := TObjectList<TObject>.Create;
end; 

constructor TMyObjectContainer<T>.Create; 
begin
  FData.Free;
  inherited;
end; 

function TMyObjectContainer<T>.Data(index: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T(FData.Items[index]);
end;
```